# Creating unit tests for default function parameters in ES6

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, frontend, code-coverage

Code below is able to parse a specific response from server. In order to make sure the response will be an empty array like output when the serviceResponse param is undefined, I use an default value provided by ES6 features.

I would like to know if you know better way to covering or **testing the default function value defined on locationHistoryParser function**.

*Source*

```javascript
function _getLagLngCoordinates(coordinates) {
 ...
}

function _getCoordinates(coordinates) {
  return coordinates.locations ?
    _getLagLngCoordinates(coordinates.locations) :
    _getLagLngCoordinates(coordinates);
}


function locationHistoryParser(serviceResponse = '[]') {
  return _getCoordinates(JSON.parse(serviceResponse));
}
```

*Test suite*

```javascript
describe('locationHistoryParser', () => {

  describe('retrieving a valid response', function () {

    describe('managing an array of objects', function () {
      it('should return an array of coordinates parsed properly', () => {
        ...
      });
    });

    describe('managing an object with locations key', function () {
      it('should return an array of coordinates parsed properly', () => {
        ...
      });
    });
  });

  describe('retrieving an invalid response', function () {

    it('should return an empty array', () => {
      const inputData = undefined;
      const expectedObject = [];

      const response = locationHistoryParser(inputData);

      expect(response).toEqual(expectedObject);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: As long as you test output for particular input then everything is fine. You test shouldn't be aware of implementation details. The only thing which you can improve is to get rid of `const inputData = undefined;`

Comment: @adelura Thanks for your answer. You are right, I do not need to declare `inputData` variable. Just calling `locationHistoryParser` function with no parameters.